# Chamar uma função que retorna uma array C#

Tags: c#, array, .net, tipagem, return

Eu preciso que o usuário digite um número que vai ser a quantidade de números a serem calculados, exemplo: se eu digitar 4, vão ser 4 números diferentes pra fazer determinada ação(somar, subtrair, multiplicar ou dividir). Pra isso eu tentei criar uma função que me retorna uma *array*:

```
public int quantNum(int quantidadeNumeros)
    {
        //Cria a array que vai armazenar os valores a serem calculados.
        int[] numerosCalcular = new int[quantidadeNumeros];

        return numerosCalcular[quantidadeNumeros];
    }
```

Eu não sei se ta certo essa função, por que eu não consigo chamar ela no escopo principal do meu programa que está assim:

```
string mensagemIinicio = "Bem vindo a calculadora do console 0.1 Alpha.";

        Console.WriteLine(mensagemIinicio);
        Console.WriteLine("Por favor insira quantos números você quer calcular.");
        int quantNumCalc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Verifica se o usuário digitou mais de um número e retorna uma mensagem
        while (quantNumCalc < 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operação inválida. Digite mais de um número(ERRO 0001)");
            Console.WriteLine("pressione qualquer tecla e aperte enter para tentar novamente.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(mensagemIinicio);
            Console.WriteLine("Por favor insira quantos números você quer calcular.");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            quantNum(x);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Tem vários problemas nesse código, por isso eu recomendo procurar aprender de uma forma mais estruturada, aprender fazer errado não é aprender.

Se a digitação não for um número inteiro seu código quebra, fiz da forma que não deixa a pessoa digitar qualquer além de validar que o número seja dentro da faixa desejada.

Note que aproveitei e eliminei redundância de código, não faça duas vezes o que pode ser feito apenas.

Não faz sentido criar uma função que faz só isso, mas se for criar mesmo então pelo menos dê um nome que diga o que ela faz. Aí basta criar o *array* sem maiores complicações. O erro que acontece é que o tipo de retorno é um inteiro e você está retornando um *array* de inteiros, portanto objetos completamente diferentes, portanto faça o retorno ser o que está retornando.

Também guardei o *array* em uma variável, caso contrário n~]ao poderá fazer nada com o retorno.

Eu não pedia para a pessoa apertar um tecla e limpar a tela, mas deixei assim. Eu também mudaria algumas coisas no texto, mas não mexi.

Assim fica melhor:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Bem vindo a calculadora do console 0.1 Alpha.");
        int quantNumCalc;
        while (true) {
            WriteLine("Por favor insira quantos números você quer calcular.");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out quantNumCalc) || quantNumCalc < 2) {
                WriteLine("Operação inválida. Digite mais de um número(ERRO 0001)");
                WriteLine("pressione qualquer tecla e aperte enter para tentar novamente.");
                ReadLine();
                Clear();
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        var array = CriaArray(quantNumCalc);
    }
    
    public static int[] CriaArray(int quantidadeNumeros) => new int[quantidadeNumeros];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oP2oPV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nCBZoM). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/LoopEntry.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta meu amigo! Então cara eu to no começo da caminhada então tem MUITA coisa que eu não sei ainda, eu só to tentando por em prática as coisas que eu já aprendi até aqui entende? Enfim obrigado pela ajuda;

Comment: @BRKiHeL veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.