# Como limitar o maior valor numérico a ser digitado no C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, framework

Queria ter um número máximo no comando:
salario = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine());
Exemplo: se passar de 4000 será inválido.

Comment: Não faça como a resposta abaixo, essa forma é errada, mesmo que pareça que funcione. Um exemplo  melhor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471939/101. Na verdade perguntas assim (que não são enunciados que a pessoa só pede para fazer o código) tem em dezenas aqui no site, seria só pesquisar, exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/336749/101. Note que aqui resolve outros problemas. Outra forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/348157/101

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas de resolver esse problema. No caso, como você está solicitando um input do usuário, uma opção seria colocar uma condição dentro de um loop, impedindo o loop de terminar enquanto o usuário não coloca um valor dentro do range que você precisa. Por exemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine ("entre o valor:");
       double salario = -1;
       do {
           salario = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine());
           if (salario > 4000) {
               Console.WriteLine("salário deve ser menor que 4000...");
               salario = -1;
           }
       } while (salario == -1);
      
    
       Console.WriteLine("salario={0}",salario);
```

Comment: Se o usuário digitar ao letra ao invés de um número, o que acontece?